# Building a web page without having internet access

Tags: html, browser

I want to build a web site using my laptop in areas where I often do not have internet access - no active browser.  How do I check my pages to see how things are going without a browser?

Comment: what do you mean by no active browser?

Comment: Tiger Scott Thanks for asking "active browser" I have several browsers on my laptop the thing is I have a job that gives me a lot of free time so I'm learning HTML but there's no internet service available.  When I want to see how my page is coming along it won't render or compile or whatever it's called.

Comment: Are you writing straight HTML? Or something like PHP/JSP/ASP/etc?

Answer (score 0):

Just drag-and-drop the .html file into your favourite web-browser. It should open up with the "file:///" protocol automatically.

Comment: Thanks EthanB I'll try that the next time I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: It helps to figure it out while you have internet access. Because then you can ask more questions/find more answers on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: EthanB, thanks for the comment. The thing is I have a job that gives me lots of free time so I'm learning HTML on my laptop but there's no internet access.  When I run the page it won't display in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a local web server installed on your machine for development.

For example, Mac OSX comes with Apache pre-installed. You might have to activate it. You can also install a server language like PHP or Python. Again, OSX comes with those pre-installed, might just need activation. Google how to set up a local server on the type of OS you have.

You should try to replicate the type of server setup you will be using in production.

That will permit you to code locally and test in your browser.

You should also use some kind of versioning system like Git. So, you code on your local machine, then you can push your code to the cloud once in a while for backup. When you're ready, upload your code to the production server and try it out.

Comment: This sounds like good advice and a lot to chew on for me. I'll start nibbling on it right away.